# Why does the Rust standard library have so much unsafe code?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I was looking at `String` in the standard library and there was so much `unsafe` code like this one:

```rust
    #[inline]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub fn remove(&mut self, idx: usize) -> char {
        let ch = match self[idx..].chars().next() {
            Some(ch) => ch,
            None => panic!("cannot remove a char from the end of a string"),
        };

        let next = idx + ch.len_utf8();
        let len = self.len();
        unsafe {
            ptr::copy(self.vec.as_ptr().add(next), self.vec.as_mut_ptr().add(idx), len - next);
            self.vec.set_len(len - (next - idx));
        }
        ch
    }
```

Why there is so much `unsafe` code in the standard library? How is the language still safe?

Comment: performance and safety do not play well together, they sacrificed safety to provide faster library functions. separate note - there is no such thing as safe language, rust provides some features which prevent some well known safety problems, but it does not make it "safe language"

Comment: ptr::copy is unsafe because your a giving it raw pointer and doing memory manipulation without bounds check and stuff, but the bounds checks are done before, so what they are doing is actually sound and safe, but the compiler can't know that. That's why they use unsafe, they are telling the compiler "we know what we are doing".

Comment: at the core, rust is not safe, there is a lot of memory manipulation that need unsafe. But that does'nt mean it's actually unsafe, it just marks some block as possible "failure points", and they are tested. Making a vec without the use of unsafe is impossible. But you can still do safe and sound memory manipulation in unsafe blocks.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question if I've ever heard one. There's no objective measure for what is or isn't "too much".

Comment: (...that said, if you look at, say, a JVM implementation, you'll see a ton of "unsafe" code implementing the interpreter itself; the achievable/reasonable goal is to have the unsafe code live only in well-understood places that are very well tested, to the point that they live under the hood of an abstraction such that only language implementers need to worry about whether that abstraction is correct)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a misconception here that using `unsafe` is automatically *unsound* and will cause memory errors. It does not. In fact, you are not allowed to cause memory errors even in `unsafe` code blocks; if you do, then the code will exhibit undefined behavior and the whole program is ill-defined. The point of `unsafe` is to allow things that the *compiler* cannot ensure are actually safe. That responsibility falls to the developer to ensure the code does not invoke undefined behavior by understanding the safety requirements required to use `unsafe` syntax, functions, and other items.

The design philosophy for writing and using `unsafe` functions is if some set of parameters or circumstances may cause a function to exhibit undefined behavior, then it must be marked `unsafe` and should be documented what the safe parameters and circumstances are. The caller must then abide by this documentation within an `unsafe` block. The flip side of this design philosophy is that if a function is *not* marked `unsafe`, then *no* possible parameters or circumstances may cause undefined behavior.

In this situation, shifting bytes around in memory is not always safe so you must use `unsafe` to call `ptr::copy`. However, the method `.remove()` is not marked `unsafe` so whatever happens in the `unsafe` block must be safe if the developers of the Rust standard library have done their job, and I'm sure they have. You can see that any possible input is bounds-checked and what is being `copy`'d is within the already allocated block. The only way this could cause undefined behavior is if there was already undefined behavior or broken invariants before calling this function.

---

You cannot build the Rust standard library without using `unsafe`. The underlying manual memory management that computers are based on is inherently fraught with memory foot-guns, however you can build off of these "unsafe" operations with guarantees that make them safe.

Some of the `unsafe`'ty is required, but other instances are simply for performance reasons. Safe abstractions may require many checks to ensure they are safe, especially if any kind of dynamicism is involved, but if your existing invariants are encoded correctly, then using `unsafe` can avoid those checks while still being safe. In this function, it probably *could* have been done entirely safely by just relying on other `self.vec` methods (which would have `unsafe` internally at some point), but it may include additional bounds checks that would be entirely unnecessary.

The standard library is expected to operate with as little overhead as possible, while staying safe (unless the function is marked `unsafe` of course).